# Charging Capacitors Multiple Times

Tags: capacitor, charge

I was thinking about "charging" capacitors. If you had a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f38U4z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, the 10 milivolt power source will not be sufficient to charge the 200 microFarad capacitor. If I disconnected the capacitor after it exhausted to power source, is it possible to connect it to another power source and continue charging?

Comment: A 10mV source can indeed charge a cap, 200 uF or even 2,000 farads.  Assuming that you want it charged to 10 mV.  That is a valid use of a cap in some applications.

Comment: First, millivolts is not a measure of power. It seems you meant to say "voltage source"? Second, your whole question makes little sense. A 10 mV source will charge a cap, whether 200 uF or some other value, to 10 mV. Therefore saying it is not sufficient to "charge the cap", whatever that is supposed to mean, makes little sense. If you're going to use real electronics terms, use them correctly.  If you don't know the right terms, learn them or find some other way to describe things.

Comment: As the circuit is drawn, it is *obvious* that the capacitor is, in fact, fully charged as there is *no* current.  I do not know what you meant to draw or what you may be thinking but, in the circuit you have drawn, the voltage across the capacitor is *constant* (10mV) and, thus, the current through the capacitor is *zero*, i.e., it is fully charged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, no power supply will ever charge a capacitor! This is due to the fact that in theory, capacitor is charged when its voltage equals supply voltage.

The simplest charging equation is \$V_c=V_s(1-e^{-\frac{t}{t_0}})\$, where \$V_c\$ is capacitor voltage, \$V_s\$ is the voltage source voltage, \$t\$ is the time during which capacitor is charged and \$t_0\$ is the RC time constant of the charging circuit, where C is the capacitance of the capacitor and R is the series resistance in the path of the capacitor. A solution to the equation will show that the voltages will be equal only when the time \$t\$ reaches infinity.

There is also the "practical" charge definition of charged capacitor. If I remember correctly, capacitor is considered charged after 6 time constants have passed. At this point, the capacitor's voltage will be more than 99% of the voltage source voltage.

Now about your question:
First, the circuit you posted breaks the assumptions needed for theoretical analyses, since you have no resistance in series with the capacitor. In theory, the capacitor will take infinite current in infinitely short amount of time and the voltage source will be able to produce the needed current.

In a real circuit, you will always have some resistance from the voltage source, wires connecting the capacitor, capacitor's own internal resistance and so on. They will all together produce the resistance R for the time constant equation.

Finally, about charging a capacitor at a different voltage source: An ideal capacitor, when disconnected from a voltage source, will maintain its voltage since there is nothing to drain the energy from the capacitor. In a real-world situation, capacitor will have some losses. Term used if capacitor leakage, if you want to research it further. Basically, the insulation between plates of the capacitor is not perfect and some charge will go from one plate to another. Depending on the type of the capacitor, that process can be slow or it can take a very long amount of time. Those losses are often modeled a s a
resistor parallel to the capacitor.

So a real world capacitor when disconnected from a voltage source will start discharging and how quickly it discharged depends on its type. If you during that time connect the capacitor to another voltage source, capacitor will work to match its voltage to the voltage of the new source. This can go both ways: If the voltage of the source if higher than capacitor's voltage, then capacitor will continue to absorb energy and will be charged. If the voltage source's voltage is lower than capacitor, capacitor will start providing energy to the rest of the circuit and its voltage will drop to match the voltage of the source.

So yes, you can continue charging a capacitor with another voltage source.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can disconnect the capacitor from a low voltage source and connect it to a higher voltage source. It will then charge up to the higher voltage.

By the way...When a capacitor is "fully" charged is usually taken to be when its voltage equals that of the supply, so by that definition, the capacitor actually is fully charged to 10mV.  In other cases you could define full charge as being close to the rated voltage (but leaving some margin for safety).